# Changing Symbology Reflected in Others?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

In ArcMap, I have a basemap that a couple people use at once and since I tend to make a lot of changes I've just copied the basemap but the layers are the same.

As I am changing the symbology of my basemap and their respective layers, will the changes be reflected in their maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Layers are snapshots in time, so if you want others to see your changes, you need to save a map or lyr files (different filetype in Pro) out to a shared space. Then map users need to refresh their maps by adding saved layers back in to their maps. That is how symbology works; however, data changes should be reflected to everyone immediately if the source location has not changed.